# need Help dokan and c# creating virtual disk

Tags: c#, virtual, dokan, virtual-disk

I want to create virtual disk using c# and dokan and I need code hint or api for  or I want to know how to work with them because when I search on google I didn,t to find and result

Answer (score 1):

I just updated the dokan dotnet wrapper and samples. I believe it's what you're looking for. See https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokan-dotnet

Comment: i will check it and tell you